# How to get project version from Mavens's pom in Ant

Tags: maven-2, ant

I have maven project and ant task for it.
In ant task i want to get version property from pom.xml.
How to get it?

In pom.xml: `<version>2.03.010</version>`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Maven Ant tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html) provide some goals for [POM processing](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/pom.html)

To access the version from a POM, you can use the following:

```
<artifact:pom id="mypom" file="pom.xml" />

<echo>The version is ${mypom.version}</echo>
```

Update: To use the tasks. You will need to install them. [Install instructions](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/installation.html)

You can either:

1. Place the JAR in your Ant lib directory, include it in the CLASSPATH environment variable
2. Pass it in to Ant using the -lib command line parameter
3. Use a typedef declaration. This allows you to store the Ant Tasks' library anywhere you like and put it's location in the build file.

With option  2. you modify your project as follows to make ant aware of the maven-ant-tasks schema:

```
<project ... xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant">
  ...
</project>
```

With option 3. You specify the typedef as follows (assuming the maven-ant-tasks jar is in the lib directory of your project):

```
<project ... xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant">
  ...
  <path id="maven-ant-tasks.classpath" path="lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.0.10.jar" />
  <typedef resource="org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml"
       uri="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant"
       classpathref="maven-ant-tasks.classpath" />
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: I have an error. What i nedd to add?

build.xml:11: The prefix "artifact" for element "artifact:pom" is not bound.

Comment: The Maven ant tasks are not part of the Ant install. You need to add them.

Answer (score 11):

If what you want is just to read values from pom.xml with what's included in ant already, you can use the XmlProperty task:

```
<xmlproperty file="pom.xml" prefix="pom" />
<echo>The version is ${pom.project.version}</echo>
```

The Maven Ant Tasks are no longer maintained, by the way.

Comment: This always works and it's a lot simpler than the accepted answer.

Comment: Great approach.

Comment: I preferred this approach since it does not require any additional dependencies.
Although it would not resolve any existing placeholder in `pom.xml`.