# artifact:install pushes the super-pom instead of the POM I define

Tags: maven-3, maven-ant-tasks

I have a POM defined in the Ant file, the build works correctly, pulling the correct artifacts from the Repository, however, the artifact:install tasks pushes to 'super-pom' instead of the pom I specify

I use the following POM file

```
<project name="my-proj" default="build" 
         xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant">

  <!-- Define the Maven tasks -->
  <path id="mvn.classpath" 
        path="${env.MAVEN_HOME}/lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.1.jar" />
  <typedef resource="org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml"
           uri="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant"
           classpathref="mvn.classpath" />


  <target name="set-deps">
    <artifact:pom id="jar.pom" packaging="jar"
                  groupId="com.me" artifactId="my-proj" 
                  version="1.0-SNAPSHOT">
      <dependency groupId="commons-logging" 
                  artifactId="commons-logging" 
                  version="1.1.1"/>
    </artifact:pom>

    <artifact:dependencies filesetId="project.jar.files" 
          pomRefId="jar.pom"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="set-deps">
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/output/casses"/>
    <javac srcdir="${basedir}/src" 
           destdir="${basedir}/output/classes" 
           classpathref="project.jar.files" />
  </target>

  <target name="build" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="output/${project.name}.jar" 
         basedir="${basedir}/output/classes"/>
  </target>

  <target name="install" depends="build">
    <echo message="Installing JAR file - ${project.name}.jar"/>
    <echo message=" groupId - ${jar.pom.groupId}"/>
    <echo message="artifactId - ${jar.pom.artifactId}"/>
    <echo message=" version - ${jar.pom.version}"/>
    <artifact:install file="${basedir}/output/${project.name}.jar" 
          pomRefId="jar.pom"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Calling `ant build` will build the JAR file correctly, so the POM is being set up correctly by the Ant script (at least from a dependency point of view).

However, calling `ant install` results in the JAR being installed on the local repository as super-pom version 1.0. installing a second time fails as a full version (1.0, no SNAPSHOT) already exists on the repository and only SNAPSHOT versions can be overwritten.

I've set the groupId/artifactId/version on the POM. How come they are not being picked up? I've tried setting these again on the install task (thinking maybe there were undocumented attributes for the task), but this task does not accept these attributes.

In fact, the correct values will get displayed before the install, so the POM knows it's groupId/artifactId/version, but still fails the install using these settings.

BTW, if it's any help, I'm using the 2.1.1 maven-ant-tasks JAR file, but the Maven version I have installed is 3.0.2 (not sure whether the tasks make external calls to the Maven Jars or if the functionality is internal to the ant task Jar).

PS. I've tried placing the dependencies in an external POM file and this seems to work, the `pom.xml` contains nothing but the dependencies and the groupId/artifactId/version (same as the in-memory pom defined above), the artifact:pom changes to:

```
<artifact:pom id="jar.pom" file="ant-pom.xml"/>
```

Nothing else changes, but `ant install` now works correctly. Is this a bug in the maven-ant-tasks or is there something I'm missing?

Where I'm working now use Ant, and I want to avoid giving more files to be managed as part of the build process. If I need to I will, but I'd rather avoid it!

Comment: Never mind. I read the Maven-ant-tasks iissues log and it's already logged as a bug (issue 170 - http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MANTTASKS-170).

Comment: I just ran into this same issue with version 2.1.3. Is there no time frame on when this will be fixed?

Comment: There does not seem to be a time frame for a fix. However, while annoying, it's a fairly easy issue to work around (Just write out the POM to disk, then use this disk based POM).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, in lieu of waiting for a fix for this issue, I went with a work-around. I write out the POM in the install, then use the disk-based POM for the install:

```
...
<target name="install" ...
  ...
  <artifact:writepom pomRefId="jar.pom" file="${basedir}/output/${project.name}-pom.xml" />
  <artifact:pom id="disk-based.pom" file="${basedir}/output/${project.name}-pom.xml" />

  <artifact:install file="${basedir}/output/${project.name}.jar" 
      pomRefId="disk-based.pom"/>
</target>
...
```

Hope this helps.